# Does using preset=placebo or veryslow option also decrease decode time?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, mpeg, mpeg4

When using `h.264` I use `preset=placebo` option. It increases encoding efficiency, but I don't know I feel like it is also increasing decoding time. Is it right or it doesn't affect decoding time at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `null` muxer to test it. As stated in [Null - FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Null)

> The [null muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#null) does not generate any output file. It is mainly useful for testing or benchmarking purposes.

This page provides a command line to check this out:

> To test decoding and demuxing (using null muxer):
>
> `ffmpeg -i input -f null -`

If your video is too short, you can try running a certain number of times. If you are using Windows, you can run `cmd.exe` and use the following to make the test 100 times:

`for /l %a in (1,1,100) do ffmpeg -i input -f null -`